# Would a set of non-clustered index work better than a clustered index for my large table?

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning, clustered-index

I'm trying to create an index over a table with potentially 100 million rows. Right now I have the following columns:

```
name="date", type ="DATE"
name="account_id", type ="INT64"
name="group_id", type ="INT64"
name="run_id", type ="INT64"
name="page_id", type ="INT64"
name="page_name", type ="LONGVARCHAR"
name="countable", type ="INT64"
name="viewing_object_id", type ="INT64"
name="viewing_object_title", type ="LONGVARCHAR"
```

Where each unique `group_id` belongs to a single `account_id` (each account has multiple groups) and each unique `run_id` belongs to a single `group_id` (each group has multiple runs). In comparison, `viewing_object_id` can be associated with multiple `page_id`.

My most common query is going to be of the type:

```
SELECT 
  MAX_BY(viewing_object_title, date) AS viewing_object_title,
  MAX_BY(page_name, date) AS page_name,
  SUM(countable) AS countable
FROM my_table
WHERE account_id = %d
  AND date >= DATE(%s)
  AND date <= DATE(%s)
GROUP BY
  viewing_object_id
```

But sometimes I also include `AND page_id = %d`. And other times I also filter on `group_id` and `run_id`.

```
WHERE account_id = %d
  AND group_id = %d
  AND run_id = %d
```

I'm thinking that I have a few options:

*1) Use the following non-clustered indices without a clustered index (maintain heap structure).*

```
[
  [account_id, viewing_object_id, date],
  [account_id, page_id, viewing_object_id, date],
  [account_id, group_id, run_id, viewing_object_id, date]
  [account_id, group_id, page_id, viewing_object_id, date]
]
```

I'm thinking that this would take up a ton of space. But surely it wouldn't be the same amount of space as having 500 million rows right? These indices match to all of the query types that I would want to run. And because data is added each day in a pipeline, I'm not that concerned about write performance.

*2) Use the following clustered index: `[account_id, date, page_id]`.*

This lets me have really fast searches when I'm specifically loading everything associated with an account over a date range, including when I filter by the `page_id`. But it seems like if I were to use `group_id` or `run_id` I'd end up having to do a full table scan.

Not really sure how to make this trade-off or if I'm thinking of this the right way. Are one of these options clearly wrong for how I'd want to index my data?

Comment: Please remove one of the tags `sql-server` or `mysql` as appropriate. How many rows approximatley would a specific `account_id`, and `(account_id, page_id)` and `(account_id,groups_id,run_id)` be respect to the total table size might be useful.

Comment: I don't think `MAX_BY` exists in MySQL.